# is synclock in multithreading avoids deadlock

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have a multithreading program where I need to avoid deadlock. Is there any method to avoid deadlocks in multithreading?.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do things in the right order.

Comment: Use message-passing designs.  Deadlock is then not avoided, but is much more difficult for you to achieve :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoiding deadlock is a matter of proper design. Hacking together a multi threaded (or multi process) app is asking for trouble. Worse, testing is not adequate proof of a lack of deadlock.

You can adopt a programming paradigm suited to this sort of thing. Communicating Sequential Processes (CSP) was invented specifically to avoid deadlock, races, etc. A good pages to read is the [JCSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JCSP) page on Wikipedia. The idea makes it curiously hard to get deadlock, etc. and also you can mathematically prove (if you're feeling brave) that your design is free of such problems.

Unfortunately Microsoft have made it difficult to implement a CSP program in Windows either natively or in .NET. What's needed is a select() that works on pipes, which just doesn't exist in MS land. I hate to think what hurdles the JCSP team had to jump through to get their equivalent (Alternative in their parlance) working.

Comment: +1 - if there were fewer explicit locks and more object queueing, there would be far fewer multithreading questions.

Comment: @MartinJames, I quite agree. I just wish more students were taught that! It also occurs to me that in these days of QPI and HyperTransport that copying data through pipes isn't necessarily inefficient these days, and is possibly more efficient. I reckon it results in similar QPI/HyperTransport traffic as sharing the data. Oh, give me a modernised Transputer!

Comment: As you probably know, the standard of 'Intro to Threads' sites/books is generally bad.  My 'touchstone' for these resources is 'if it mentions join() on the first page, it sucks'.